# Prevent Google Maps API from optimising display for non-fullscreen mode

Tags: google-maps

When Google Map API initialise the map in non full screen mode (CSS positioning not absolute), it applies an inline style `position="relative"` to the `<div id="googlemap" style="position:relative"></div>` causing subsequent `$('#googlemap').toggleClass('fullscreen')` to be ignored unless I use `.fullscreen { position: absolute !important; }`.

But forcing absolute positioning does not automatically enable Google Map to operate in 100% width and height because the map is still optimised according to its initial width and height of `500px`. When the map is dragged beyond this imaginary box, the jpeg map images unloads.

How to really tell Google Map that we are currently in fullscreen mode and re-init the optimisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, the way I did is to destroy the map and reinitialize with the full screen parameters.